# Changing font size of list items and subitems

Tags: beamer, lists, fontsize, itemize

I've noticed that when I change the font size of a list, the font size is not automatically changed for its sublists. Is there a way to change the font size for a whole list?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
  {
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{author in head/foot}
      \leavevmode{\usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor}
      \hfill
      {\usebeamerfont{institute in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{institute in head/foot}\insertshortinstitute}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}
      {\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle} \hfill     \insertframenumber,/\inserttotalframenumber
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[colsep=1.5pt]{lower separation line foot}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{enumerate item}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=darkred}
\setbeamercolor{institute in head/foot}{fg=darkred}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}
{\footnotesize
\begin{itemize}
\item First item 
\item Second item
\item Third item
\item Fourth item
\item Fifth item
\begin{itemize}
\item First subitem
\item Second subitem
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

In this example, the font size of the third and fourth item would be bigger than the size of the previous list elements.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When working with beamer one always should use beamer syntax:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}


\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate body begin}{\large}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}

\begin{itemize}
\item First item 

\begin{itemize}
\item First subitem
\item Second subitem
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}


\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This simply sets the item body to a size. One level below (3rd) can be accessed via `\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subsubbody begin}{<...>}`. As one may encounter, the labels aren't properly aligned after the change of the fontsize. This is a result of beamers' manual like definition of the alignment of the labels. The orginal definition is `\defbeamertemplate*{itemize item}{default}{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}` so one needs to alter the size and the vertical position of labels. One may even need to alter the skips between the items.

Answer (score 12):

Please *always* post complete documents that show the problem. I get consistent font size when I tried your fragment, but you may have conflicting packages.

In this case it seems to be a beamer feature which you can avoid by changing one line to say

```
\footnotesize \let\small\footnotesize
```

Makes `\small` locally the same as `\foototesize` so when beamer decides to insert `\small` no harm is done. (There may be a proper beamer configuration for this I don't know beamer that well)

Original answer:

I fixed a couple of markup errors (the inner `{}` are not needed and there should be a blank line before the closing `}` of a font size command. But they make no difference in this case.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

{\footnotesize
\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
\begin{itemize}
\item Third item
\item Fourth item
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question fixing the markup errors and adding the complete code.

Comment: David appears to be quite right, as usual: there does not seem to be a Beamer-native way to ensure that all sub[sub]lists are typeset at the same size as outer lists. Possibly this is because of an assumption that lower-level lists should be smaller à la Powerpoint. I would be interested to know if anyone has a way of fixing this, preferably permanently.