# How to set the different fontsize according to different levels in an enumitem list in beamer?

Tags: beamer, lists, enumitem

I use enumitem in beamer to create a enumerate list as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\newlist{enum}{enumerate}{5}  
\setlist[enum]{label*=\arabic*., listparindent=21pt, font=\bfseries\tiny } 

\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}

\begin{enum}
\item First item 

\begin{enum}
\item First subitem
\item Second subitem

\begin{enum}
\item First subitem
\item Second subitem

\begin{itemize}
\item First subitem
\item Second subitem

\end{itemize}
\end{enum}
\end{enum}

\item Second subitem
\end{enum}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result is:
The fonts all the levels are same.
[image]

But how to set different font size with corrospending different levels in the list as follows? How to make higher level with higher text size?
[image]

Comment: You mean `.tex` source of the second beamer slide is not available with you.

Comment: The second I use {\huge \begin{enum}
\item First subitem
\item Second subitem } to make it in every level of lists. But it's dirty. How to make it better use a global setting?

Comment: I hope this may help [Changing font size of list items and subitems](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91582/15717)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. But that method works just for itemize, enumerate, doesn't for enumitem, I try \setbeamertemplate{enum subbody begin}{\tiny} It doesn't work.

Comment: Please see this [Trouble combining enumitem and beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31524/15717). When you use [beamer class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) stick to `\setbeamertemplate{}` option don't use `enumitem` package designed for other class.

Comment: I am a newbie, It seems make things more complicated. I still don't catch what should I do.

Comment: Even i am also a newbie trying to help you with what i know.

Comment: Here is an [working example](https://www.writelatex.com/82953fjvxqt) for you. I have to go for sleep. Bye

Comment: Thank you for your help! I resolve it now on another simple way.

Comment: you can post your own solution here so that it will benefit others who suffer from same issue

Answer (score 8):

I resolve this by the command  "before" in enumitem.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\newlist{enum}{enumerate}{3}  
\setlist[enum, 1]{label*=\arabic*., listparindent=21pt, font=\bfseries\tiny, before*=\huge } 
\setlist[enum, 2]{label*=\arabic*., listparindent=21pt, font=\bfseries\tiny, before*=\large }
\setlist[enum, 3]{label*=\arabic*., listparindent=21pt, font=\bfseries\tiny, before*=\small }

\setlist[itemize,1]{before*=\tiny}

\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}

\begin{enum}
\item First item 

\begin{enum}
\item First subitem
\item Second subitem

\begin{enum}
\item First subitem
\item Second subitem

\begin{itemize}
\item First subitem
\item Second subitem

\end{itemize}
\end{enum}
\end{enum}

\item Second subitem
\end{enum}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It works as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Instead of attempting to use `enumitem` with beamer, use beamer's own mechanism:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}[default]
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subsubitem}[default]

\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subbody}{size=\footnotesize}
\setbeamerfont{itemize/enumerate subsubbody}{size=\tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame title}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item 

\begin{enumerate}
\item First subitem
\item Second subitem

\begin{enumerate}
\item First subitem
\item Second subitem

\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\item Second subitem
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for not using `enumitem` within beamer!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you for your vote(s) :)